# Использование if больше одного раза или его замена

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Решил написать простого телеграмм бота. При нажатии на ReplyButton выполняется код и выводится курс валюты. Все работает, но только один раз. Потом приходится перезапускать команду в телеграмм, что не очень то и удобно.

```
def process_step(message):
    if message.text == 'USD':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Курс доллара = " + str(USD))
    elif message.text == 'EUR':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Курс евро = " + str(EUR))
    elif message.text == 'RUB':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Курс рубля = " + str(RUB))
```

Как сделать так, чтоб функция не завершалась после одного исполнения? И можно было бы сразу узнать курс другой валюты?

Comment: При нажатии на кнопки в тг, пользователю отправляются данные(курс валюты), это все парсится, если пользователь нажимает на кнопку со значением 'USD", ему выводится ответ... Но срабатывает данная конструкция только один раз, после чего приходится перезапускать команду /start в тг, каким способом можно избавиться от этого перезапуска?

Answer (score 0):

Это может быть цикл прерываемый командой стоп, хватит etc.

```
def process_step(message):
    while message.text!='Стоп':
        if message.text == 'USD':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Курс доллара = " + str(USD))
        elif message.text == 'EUR':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Курс евро = " + str(EUR))
        elif message.text == 'RUB':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Курс рубля = " + str(RUB))
```

Comment: К сожалению, бот просто отправляет n-ое кол-во сообщений, пока не остановишь его, либо не отключишь

Comment: @MaximKapko потому что нужно каждый раз считывать сообщение и заново вызывать функцию с новым аргументом.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, уже походу сам догодался ))

Answer (score 0):

```
'''def process_step(message):
    if message.text == 'USD':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Курс доллара = " + str(USD))
        send_welcome(message)
    elif message.text == 'EUR':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Курс евро = " + str(EUR))
        send_welcome(message)
    elif message.text == 'RUB':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Курс рубля = " + str(RUB))
        send_welcome(message)'''
```

Пока что решил сделать так, просто перезапускать ф-ию, после каждого выбора пользователя, только нужно заменить функцию приветствия на что-то более вразумительное ))) ну и костыль получилося, походу...